# Using a static member variable to count number of objects created

Tags: oop, static, d

I am trying to create a dynamic array of objects, using a static variable as a pointer to the next available array index. I'm sure there is a better way to do this...

class storing the dynamic array:

```
import std.stdio;

import DataRow;

class Database{

public:
    this(){ /* intentionally left blank */}

    void addRow(DataRow input){
        this.db[count] = input;
        writeln(count);
        count++;
    }

private:
    static uint count;
    DataRow[] db;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D arrays can be appended to with the `~=` operator, and keep track of their own `length`. You shouldn't need to keep track of the length yourself:

```
void addRow(DataRow input){
    this.db ~= input;
    writeln(db.length); // number of rows in db
}
```

Based on your example, I'm not sure if this is what you intended. Each `Database` instance has its own member `db`, but all would share the same `count` variable as you declared it as `static`.
Unless you have a good reason for keeping a static counter (which would track the number of rows added across *all* instances of `Database`), I would just rely on each array to track its own length.

Comment: there would only be one db object, like a Singleton. but, like you said, i was going about it the wrong way.